# Articles related to Hypernate in .NET

Tags: .net

I'm looking for articles related Hypernate in .net

Can anyone recommend some?

Comment: You mean Hibernate? Or NHibernate?

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely that you're *really* after [hypernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hypernate/) (which appears to be a solo project without a release in 3 years). Did you perhaps mean [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org)? If so, you're likely to be able to find what you want just by searching when you use the right name :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for articles about NHibernate (check the spelling)?
Search stackoverflow or google for NHibernate and you will find lots of articles.

The website of the NHibernate project is at http://www.nhibernate.org/ (but it seems to be unavailable currently?).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Hibernate, this is [THE article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Nhibernate_Made_Simple.aspx) to read to get introduced to Nhibernate. It tooks me less than 1 hour to get started with Nhibernate. Very good to start with.